# Cordova, Appcelerator, Titanium and Haxe which is better for both desktop and mobile

Tags: cordova, appcelerator, haxe

I need something where I can write code once and that will run on desktop browser and mobile. For mobile devices it should be native or hybrid app and in desktop it should open in browser. I need very minimum device API for mobile devices since the application is basically a web application. jQuery mobile or similar library will not work since they can not built native/hybrid app for mobile devices. After some research I found Cordova, Appcelerator Titanium, haxe e.t.c but I think Cordova and Appcelerator are targeting the mobile devices only. Do anyone can help me to choose the right framework for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your details are not enough.

But choosing from Cordova, Appcelerator and haxe I'd clearly chose haxe.

Comment: I have a PHP application built in MVC. The view part is running on web browser. I want that part to be a native application for android/iOS. Cordova can do that. What I am not sure finally what should I use Cordova, Appcelerator or haxe. Why you will use haxe what is the benefit of using it over cordova?

Comment: If you already have your application ready then PhoneGap or Cordova are the ways to go. (I'd use haxe for new project because of easiness of development and ability to use any of this technologies as a backend without need to rewrite code.)

Comment: Yes I have this project ready but I am asking for future also. If haxe is easy then we will use haxe for new projects. Can you please tell me why you prefer haxe and is it able to handle complex page design that html5/CSS3 can?

Comment: Haxe is not about page design. Haxe is a typed language cross-compiled to various other languages. The point of using it is to share codebase between different platforms and languages. If you will use the backend for which html/css is available(js for example, can be used in browser or with phonegap or anything) you can use html/css directly. Yet again, it is a bit difficult to tell if it will meet all your needs. I myself am haxe developer for years already and I'm pretty comfortable with using it for various needs.

Comment: For example in 5 minutes I'll continue to work on my pet project: window manager for windows8 using nodejs with node-webkit and WinAPI as backend and my main project^ highload nodejs webserver. And haxe suits me well even for such a complex environment. For all I know, haxe code is easy to maintain, and that's a very important point for me. However the learning curve might not be that easy for someone.So my best guess for you will be to just evaluate it: try to make a simple app(js target will be best as it is the simplest one) and look if you like it.

Comment: Choosing development language/environment/toolkit is an important choice for the project(s). So spending a couple of hours evaluating available technology is totally worthwhile.

Comment: Hmm.... thanks stroncium for explanation. My need is not just backend. Our application is mainly browser based. complex UI design and functionality is a major requirement. We can achieve that by HTML5 CSS3 and JavaScript. Our backend is running on JAVA. We want some solution where the view part will be installed as native application to user. I think Cordova is best choice in that case.

Comment: Well, we also have some (very) complex webpages running on haxe. The whole point is that you can develop both server-side and client-side in the same language. All in all, it seems like you are missing the point. Try visiting http://haxe.org/ to get an understanding what haxe is.

Comment: We can develop back-end and frond end in JAVA also but we use HTML/CSS/JS for view part and we can change the template section without touching the back-end. Currently our main focus is on this view part only. The application back-end is written on JAVA and it is not going to change. What we can do is we can create view part that will communicate with back-end and render the screen. This view should open in desktop browser and on mobile devices as native app(not as webpage in mobile browser). It is also preferable that if we can maintain same code base for desktop and mobile devices.

Comment: I thought cordova will help because we can use same code base for mobile devices also.But it has some limitations. That is why I am asking if Haxe can solve this or not. For example to create a gmail like page where the data comes from APIs and my application is responsible for rendering the page. How can I do that in Haxe? I want to clear my query once more that the back end will not going to change. The backend provides APIs that the front end use and render the page. This front end will change and will be a application that will run on desktop and mobile devices as native application.

Comment: Yet again, you seemed to miss the point. What you ask from me is to copy http://haxe.org/ page here. Just go and look for yourself. You can use cordova in haxe, and whatever you want.